# unable to create MIDlet with j2me

Tags: java

i use WTK 2.5.2 . I am getting an error while running my program . the nature of error is ..

```
Unable to create MIDlet HelloMidlet
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloMidlet
 at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletState.createMIDlet(+29)
 at com.sun.midp.midlet.Selector.run(+22)
```

.. what would be the reason .. please suggest .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is you class really in default package? Check that the *fully qualified class name* is written correctly in jad file.

How are you creating and running midlet? If for example you are using Eclipse pluging it should be done automatically but if you are working with WTK directly check the jar size into jad. It must be the same.

Check the `-target` option of compiler. Probably your are compiling class for newer version of JVM that is used by WTK.

If you still have problem please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

See your JAD application descriptor it seems you have specified `HelloMidlet` as `MIDlet-class` which is non exist